# Why does python timeit check for win32 instead of win*?

Tags: python, windows, time, 64-bit

The `timeit` source that I have (python 2.7) has

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    # On Windows, the best timer is time.clock()
    default_timer = time.clock
else:
    # On most other platforms the best timer is time.time()
    default_timer = time.time
```

Yet the documentation suggests that all Windows machines behave the same

> The difference in default timer function is because on Windows,
>   clock() has microsecond granularity but time()'s granularity is 1/60th
>   of a second...

What happens on 64-bit Windows? Is `time.time` actually better on 64 bit Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that even 64 bit windows will tell you that its platform is "win32". I'm on a 64 bit Windows 7 system, and here's what I see:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'win32'
```

Consequently, 64 bit Windows will also use `time.clock`.

Comment: Also note that apparently the stdlib isn't following its own advice here... That advice on [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.platform) is to use `str.startswith`... :-)

Comment: @mgilson: `startswith` is recommended to support both Linux 2.x and 3.x (Python 3 uses just `'linux'`). Windows is always `'win32'`.